# Hi there , i'm arabic speaker , i have a confusion between the "How" and "What" in the meaning?

Tags: meaning, differences, american-english

can anyone explain the exact meaning of each word with example ??
sometimes i confused when using the word "How" with the same meaning of "What"

Comment: Can you elaborate on what aspect you find confusing, or gives some examples you aren't sure of?  The definitions are different.

Comment: sorry for the confusion , but the answer below is enough for me .

Answer (score 1):

"How" can be used to ask a question, as can "What".

Examples:

"How hot is it?"

"What is the weather outside?"

In the second example, "What" can be replaced with "How", but in the first example, "How" cannot be replaced with "What".

Here are the definitions:

how

> in what way or manner; by what means.
>   "how does it work?"
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/how)</sub>

what

> asking for information specifying something.
>   "what is your name?"
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/what)</sub>

Comment: Two things (which I've fixed for you): 1) You need to cite your sources 2) Use quote format for quotes, not code format. Otherwise this is a good answer, although the question is ill suited for this site.

Comment: thanks for your advice and your answer , this is the first question i asked in this website .